# Can you dynamically get the page number you are on in oracle apex?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I need to write to a page dynamically based on what page I am on using pl/sql. I don't know if it is possible, but can you get the page number you are on within pl/sql. For example with items you can use :P12_ITEM_NAME in order to get a certain item on a page, is there something similar to get the current page number?

Thanks.

Comment: Voted to reopen: I don't see how this question is too broad, see Justin Cave's answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're within a page, you can just use `:APP_PAGE_ID`.  But if you're within a page, you'd generally know what page you're on.

If "within PL/SQL" means that you're calling a PL/SQL procedure or function that is defined in the back end database, you'd want `nv('APP_PAGE_ID')` (you could use `v('APP_PAGE_ID')` if you want it returned as a string rather than a number for some reason).

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly. I used v('APP_PAGE_ID').